# Doubling request on bot messaging endpoint

Tags: asp.net-core, botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

I'm using MS-provided bot sample with Teams messaging extensions feature. Only posted my Azure AD creds, no more changes. Running it locally...

When a user clicks messaging extension button in Teams request arrived on `Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples.Controllers.BotController.PostAsync()` method. If this method works longer than 25 seconds, Teams show to the user error message. Docs say that it should be only 15 seconds, but it seems Teams became more tolerant these days, okay.

But in this case the second request arrives in this method after first one (it takes place even if method works 16 seconds, not 26)! It's with same body and headers besides `Authorization` header (it contains new token).

So...What does it mean? What is this behavior created for? How to prevent it?
And who does this second request after all? I look in fiddler and see only one request to MS server from my desktop Teams client. When I'm make similar request from Postman, it arrives only one time.

Comment: We are able to repro the issue, checking internally get back to you soon.

Comment: If there is no response from bot controller within 15 seconds, Teams service retry once. So, you will see double calls in your controller. So, make sure your bot respond within 15 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Copying answer from comments for better understanding:
From a scenario it is the best if the bot responds within 5 seconds. We are waiting for more, but that should not be something that the we should rely on. Also as @subba reddi said If there is no response from bot controller within 15 seconds, Teams service retry once. So, you will see double calls in your controller. So, make sure your bot respond within 15 seconds.

Comment: So it's no chances to set up Teams Service retry logic somehow? Do you have any plans on that? It's addition work to identify second request as retrying one. And I don't understand what issues such logic resolves.